# обработчик события для нескольких элементов

Tags: jquery

Как сделать аналогию в jquery для обработки события на клик по конкретному элементу класса. По типу примера

js

```
for (var i=0; i<document.getElementsByClassName('blah')) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('blah')[i].addEventListener('click', function(){console.log('ok')});
}
```

jq

```
for (var i = 0; i < $('.blah').length; i++) {
        $('.blah')[i].click(function(){
            console.log($('.blah')[i]);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если совсем по-простому, но чтобы работало на добавляемых динамически элементах, то можно так:

```js
var blah = document.body.querySelectorAll('.blah');

for (var x = 0; x < blah.length; x++) {
  blah[x].addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log('javascript_' + this.innerHTML);
  });
}



$('body').on('click', '.blah', function() {
  console.log('jquery_' + $(this).text());
});
```

```css
.blah {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blah">1</div>
<div class="blah">2</div>
<div class="blah">3</div>
<div class="blah">4</div>
<div class="blah">5</div>
```

**UPD.** Добавил вариант на чистом JS

Comment: Есть вариант минуя jquery?

Comment: @Doofy, да, сейчас добавлю

Comment: [говнокод](http://cs636825.vk.me/v636825313/fa0c/JaXtERnAmfQ.jpg) может есть способ лучше этого?

Comment: как выбрать конкретный элемент без this. console.log( $('.blah')[0] ) совсем ничего не выдает

Comment: @ddeadlink, `$('.blah').eq(0)`

Comment: @Doofy, выборку нужно делать через `querySelectorAll`, добавил вариант на чистом JS

Comment: @ddeadlink, в `$(this)` находится полностью весь объект, на который вы нажимаете, тот самый `$('.blah')[i]` из вашего вопроса, а вам что нужно, порядковый номер этого элемента или что?

Answer (score 0):

Есть такой вариант

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.qeqqe')).forEach(function(e, i) {
    e.onclick = function() {
        console.log(this.innerHTML, i);
    }
});
```

```html
<div class='qeqqe'>one</div>
<div class='qeqqe'>two</div>
<div class='qeqqe'>tree</div>
```

Comment: судя по вопросу, автору нужна была реализация именно в jquery :)

Comment: @MasterAlex, значит ответ он получил =) `$('.blah').on('click', function() {}`